# Lambda function within a lambda function in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying the below function.

I want to translate the data in 'Text' from the language it's in, which can be determined through

```
df['Language'] = df.Text.apply(lambda x: TextBlob(str(x)).detect_language())
```

Into Spanish, which can be done with:

```
.translate(from_lang='en', to= 'es')
```

I have tried the below, but I'm not sure how to nest the two function into a single statement?

```
df['Translated'] = df.Text.apply(lambda x: TextBlob(str(x)).translate(from_lang= df.Text.apply(lambda x: TextBlob(str(x))), to ='en'))
```

The input dataframe is just a single column with text statements, like:

```
Text
"I love this game, I think its great"
"really buggy, not a good experience, do not buy"
"not too bad, not too good"
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you have an example of your data? Also, have you tried defining a function and not just using lambda functions?

Comment: any reason you can't just do it in 2 steps?

Comment: I tried to do it in two steps, but then I wasn't sure how to extract the language from the newly created column and inject it into the change language statement. I'm a bit of a newbee, sorry :(

Comment: @joepattern I have added my sample data

Comment: In terms of readability, I would do this in two stages. Don't try cram everything into one line when it affects understanding. You could always have two named functions at the least

Comment: Hi @roganjosh I did try in two stages also, but If I add the newly created 'Language' column into the statement, it errors, because I guess its brining in the whole series, not just that language. So I got a bit stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using Series.apply you can use DataFrame.apply:

```
df['Translated'] = df.apply(lambda x: TextBlob(str(x.Text)).translate(from_lang=x.Language, to='en'), axis=1)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this! I get this error: AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'Text'", 'occurred at index Text')
- I'm not sure why, because I've been referring to it in all other fields

Comment: @kikee1222 my mistake, I forgot the axis=1 kwarg for apply. updated